# Organic Groups not allowing group members to view content

Tags: organic-groups

I have the following configuration set up for Organic Groups (2.x) :

(1) A content type defined called 'Organic Group'. It's defined as both a Group and a Group Content, because I need the ability for one instance of Organic Group to be a subgroup of another instance of Organic Group.

(2) An instance of 'Organic Group' called 'School Member Zone' set up. 
'School Member Zone' has group content visibility set to 'Private - accessible only to group members'.

(3) An Article on the site with 'Groups Audience' set to 'School Member Zone'. It also has 'Group Content Visibility' set to 'Private - accessible only to group members'.

(4) A user on the site 'schoolzone_member1' with a Group Membership of 'School Member Zone'.

PROBLEM -

When I log in as an anonymous user and browse to the article, I get access denied, as you would expect.

However when I log in as 'schoolzone_member1' I **still** get access denied.

Is any of the above configuration obviously wrong, or if not, how might I start debugging this problem?

Thanks,

MB